# How do i fix: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object?

Tags: python, function

I was writing a program based on the game E-Card from the anime Kaiji. I was experimenting with functions when I got an error I was unfamiliar with. It's a TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object. I believe it means that some variable along the way has been left with no data or something. I just wasn't sure and I've been looking over it for a couple of days now and am completely stumped at what I did wrong. Any help is very much appeciated.

The Code:

```
def slaveTypeGame():
  wins = 0
  enemyWins = 0
  loopNum = 4
  
  #Runs the loop three times once every round
  for i in range(3):
    enemyCards = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'E']
    running = True
    print()
    print("RESTART")
    print()

    #Runs the game lop for each round
    while running == True:
      temp = random.randint(0, 1)
      if temp == 0:
        print()
        print(random.choice(enemyinteractions))
        print()
    
      #Chooses enemy card
      enemySelection = (random.choice(enemyCards))

      #Choose my card
      cardSelection = input("Enter your selection: ")
      while not ((cardSelection == "S") or (cardSelection == "C")):
        print("Enter either S or C")
        cardSelection = input("Enter your selection: ")

      #this is the win condition 
      if cardSelection == "S" and enemySelection == "E":
        print("YOU DESTROYED HIM!!!!")
        print("Your enemy has drawn his Empourer card")
        wins = wins + 1
        running = False

      #this is the draw condition
      elif cardSelection == "C" and enemySelection == "C":
        print("DRAW")
        print("Your enemy drew his Citezen card")
        print()

      #this makes you lose
      elif cardSelection == "S" and enemySelection == "C":
        print("YOUR DEAD")
        print("A Citezen card was drawn by your enemy")
        enemyWins = enemyWins + 1
        running = False

      #this also makes you lose
      elif cardSelection == "C" and enemySelection == "E":
        print("You have died")
        print("A blunder on your part he drew his Empourer card")
        enemyWins = enemyWins + 1
        running = False

      enemyCards.remove(enemySelection)

  return wins, enemyWins

#This when you play the game multiple times and is important
def endCalc(wins1, enemyWins2):
  finalWins = 0
  finalWins = finalWins + wins1

#computes the scores and prints if ou lost or won
def endGame(wins, enemyWins):
  print()
  print("You ended with", wins, "wins")
  print("He ended with", enemyWins, "wins")
  print()

  if wins > enemyWins:
    print("You have won!!!")
  elif wins < enemyWins:
    print("You have lost")
  elif wins == enemyWins:
    print("you have drawn")

#This is the problem area
t1, t2 = slaveTypeGame()

#This the line thats causing me bother
score1, score2 = endCalc(t1, t2)

endGame(score1, score2)
```

The error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2a65c42b6517> in <module>()
    130 t1, t2 = slaveTypeGame()
    131 
--> 132 score1, score2 = endCalc(t1, t2)
    133 
    134 endGame(score1, score2)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: `endCalc` doesn't return anything explicitly. So it returns `None`. You can't assign things 2 variables to `None`

Comment: Ohhhhh I am pretty stupid, LOL, I needed to add a return statement.